# Traverse relations upwards in SurrealDB

Tags: sql, surrealdb

### The question: How do I use the arrow syntax from surrealdb in the right way, so that I can traverse the relation tree?

I can't find good examples on google and the documentation does not explain it in detail. Not enough for me though.

#### What I have:

I put some tables with locations in my db and related them. The relations are stored in the table `location`.

These are some tables I have:

- prefecture
- village
- building

The "Relation-Structure" looks like this:

- **1** etc.

  - **...**

    - **4** prefecture

      - **5** village

        - **6** building

          - **7** etc.

Select to find the relations between 4, 5 and 6:

```sql
select * from location where in = village:Akashima or out = village:Akashima and in = prefecture:Chizaki or out = prefecture:Chizaki
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "time": "114.1µs",
    "status": "OK",
    "result": [
      {
        "id": "location:e9thhtqa89mvf9caa0yp",
        "in": "prefecture:Chizaki",
        "out": "village:Akashima"
      },
      {
        "id": "location:j0y4zixgkl7bfohr6cib",
        "in": "village:Akashima",
        "out": "building:WirtshausYukihira"
      },
      {
        "id": "location:lurrfhzvawjmyp06zoh5",
        "in": "village:Akashima",
        "out": "building:HausYukihira"
      },
      {
        "id": "location:zlkd055c75ifk7oi2pqm",
        "in": "country:DE",
        "out": "prefecture:Chizaki"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

#### Things I tried:

I tried this query:

```sql
SELECT <-village FROM location WHERE out = "building:HausYukihira"
```

The result is what I wanted at this point:

```json
[
  {
    "time": "242.3µs",
    "status": "OK",
    "result": [
      {
        "<-village": [
          "village:Akashima"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So now I want to know in which prefecture the village is located in, so I tried:

```sql
SELECT prefecture<-village FROM location WHERE out = "building:HausYukihira"
```

and

```sql
SELECT <-prefecture<-village FROM location WHERE out = "building:HausYukihira"
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "time": "97.3µs",
    "status": "OK",
    "result": [
      {
        "<-prefecture": {
          "<-village": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can't figure out where I have to put the next arrows.

---

### Edit:

SQL for creating sample data

```sql
CREATE prefecture:Chizaki
SET
name = 'Chizaki',
type= 'prefecture';

CREATE prefecture:Ijima
SET
name = 'Ijima',
type= 'prefecture';

CREATE prefecture:Shiratama
SET
name = 'Shiratama',
type= 'prefecture';

CREATE village:Kengata
SET
name = 'Kengata',
type= 'village';

CREATE village:Akashima
SET
name = 'Akashima',
type= 'village';

CREATE building:HausYukihira
SET
name = "Haus der Yukihira's",
type= 'building';

CREATE building:WirtshausYukihira
SET
name = "Wirtshaus der Yukihira's",
type= 'building';

CREATE country:KR
SET
name = 'KR',
type= 'country';

CREATE country:DE
SET
name = 'DE',
type= 'country';


RELATE country:DE->location->prefecture:Shiratama;
RELATE country:DE->location->prefecture:Ijima;
RELATE country:DE->location->prefecture:Chizaki;

RELATE prefecture:Chizaki->location->village:Akashima;
RELATE prefecture:Shiratama->location->village:Kengata;

RELATE village:Akashima->location->building:HausYukihira;
RELATE village:Akashima->location->building:WirtshausYukihira;

-- select * from location;
-- select * from location where in = village:Akashima or out = village:Akashima and in = prefecture:Chizaki or out = prefecture:Chizaki;
```

Comment: could you provide some sample data so we can try this locally?

Comment: I appended the sql for copy paste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend starting the query on the `building` table.

- To get the village, traverse via the `location` table and find the village: `<-location<-village`
- To get the prefecture, traverse via `location` and `village` again. But now you also traverse from the `village` to the `location` to get the `prefecture`: `<-location<-village<-location<-prefecture`

```sql
SELECT 
  *, 
  <-location<-village as village,
  <-location<-village<-location<-prefecture as prefecture
FROM building
WHERE id = "building:HausYukihira"
```

result:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "building:HausYukihira",
    "name": "Haus der Yukihira's",
    "prefecture": [
      "prefecture:Chizaki"
    ],
    "type": "building",
    "village": [
      "village:Akashima"
    ]
  }
]
```

---

But we can also query the `location` table following the same logic.

```sql
SELECT <-village<-location<-prefecture as prefecture
FROM location 
WHERE out = "building:HausYukihira"
```

result:

```json
[
  {
    "prefecture": [
      "prefecture:Chizaki"
    ]
  }
]
```